# Cloud Functions Local HTTP Trigger

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

What is the correct way to execute/trigger Firebase functions [locally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) when utilizing `firebase-tools` functionality `firebase serve`?

Let's say you have the function:

```
exports.hello = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World');
});
```

If normally one would trigger the production function `hello` by making an HTTP POST call to something like `https://us-central1-foobar.cloudfunctions.net/hello` like:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://us-central1-foobar.cloudfunctions.net/hello
```

How would one structure the HTTP POST url when using the `firebase serve` locally? The goal is to debug/test the function prior to launching to production in a firebase hosting + functions solution.

Would one target `localhost:5000` instead of `https://us-central1-foobar`?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation on https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator put it:

> This command outputs a URL where you can view or test your Firebase hosting content and HTTP functions.

So when you start the local emulator it prints the URL for the function. In my case:

```
$ firebase serve --only functions

=== Serving from '/Users/puf/Github/zero-to-app-io-2017'...

i  functions: Preparing to emulate HTTPS functions. Support for other event types coming soon.
✔  functions: cleanupMojaic: http://localhost:5002/z2a-emojichat/us-central1/cleanupMojaic
```